# Kolmogorov complexity of substring if string is divided according to rule

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, kolmogorov-complexity, descriptive-complexity

> Denote the plain Kolmogorov complexity of a string $u$ by $C(u)$. Now let $u$ be a string of length $n$ with $C(u) \ge n - O(1)$ and suppose $u = u_1 \cdots u_{\log n}$, a subdivision of the string. Further suppose for each $1 \le i \le \log n$ we have $|u_i| = n/\log n$. Show that
>   $$
>  C(u_i) \ge n / \log n - O(1)
> $$
>   for all $1 \le i \le \log n$.

Any ideas how to solve this? If I have a algorithm to compute $u_i$, then I can describe the rest $u_1 \cdots u_{i-1} u_{i+1} \cdots u_{\log n}$ literally, but to compose $u$ out of them I need the information where to place $u_i$ (i.e. as the $i$-th substring), but for storing that I need additional information, but by this additional bits I do not have
$$
 C(u) \le C(u_i) + (n - |u_i|)
$$
from which the above would follow. So any hints?

This is [Exercise 2.2.2 (c)](https://books.google.de/books?id=LKEmB_GQ53QC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA116#v=onepage&q&f=false) from *An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications*.